# Merge queries with difference in conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, union

I have 2 SQL (Oracle 11g) queries :

```
select x1,x2,x3
from X
where x1 = a and x2 = b;

select x1,x2,x3
from X
where x1 = a and x2 = b and x3 = c;
```

They select the same columns in table X but difference in conditions. I use UNION for merge result:

```
select x1,x2,x3,'Q1' as QueryCode
from X
where x1 = a and x2 = b
  UNION
select x1,x2,x3,'Q2' as QueryCode
from X
where x1 = a and x2 = b and x3 = c;
```

But in this case, my table have too large data and I don't want to select it too many times. Can someone give me an idea for optimal way to build a query returning the same results?

Comment: In case,  x1=a, x2=b, x3=c, do you want two rows or a single row?

Comment: I want get 1 row for each QueryCode => 2rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can fetch all the needed rows, adding `OR` between first and second filters, and then separate them in `UNION`. And using hint `/*+ materialize */` we assure that data from `original_table` is selected only once and filtered results stored in memory as `sub_table` for current query execution.

Yes, it's not beatiful to duplicate code `(x1 = a AND x2 = b)` and `(x1 = a AND x2 = b AND x3 = c)`, but in this case of **too large data** we make another good trade-off: a small  duplication for a brilliant performance.

```
WITH
  sub_table AS (SELECT /*+ materialize */ x1, x2, x3
                  FROM original_table
                 WHERE (x1 = a AND x2 = b)             -- first filter
                    OR (x1 = a AND x2 = b AND x3 = c)  -- second filter
  )
SELECT  x1, x2, x3, 'Q1' AS querycode
  FROM sub_table
 WHERE x1 = a AND x2 = b              -- first filter (repeated)

UNION

SELECT x1, x2, x3, 'Q2' AS querycode
  FROM sub_table
 WHERE x1 = a AND x2 = b AND x3 = c;  -- second filter (repeated)
```

If we don't care of rows order, there is another approach wothout `UNION`:

```
SELECT x1, x2, x3,
       CASE
       WHEN x1 = a AND x2 = b THEN 'Q1'
       WHEN x1 = a AND x2 = b AND x3 = c THEN 'Q2'
       END AS marker
  FROM original_table
 WHERE CASE
       WHEN x1 = a AND x2 = b THEN 'Q1'
       WHEN x1 = a AND x2 = b AND x3 = c THEN 'Q2'
       END IS NOT NULL;
```

Still have an imperfection of code duplication, but it's a price
for querying table with large data. In other words, for a small table
we could use concise code with subquery, which is more memory-intensive:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT x1, x2, x3,
               CASE
               WHEN x1 = a AND x2 = b THEN 'Q1'
               WHEN x1 = a AND x2 = b AND x3 = c THEN 'Q2'
               END AS marker
          FROM original_table) t
 WHERE t.marker IS NOT NULL;
```

And finally, in Oracle 12c we can incapsulate this duplicated `CASE` into a function:

```
WITH
  FUNCTION get_marker(x1 CHAR, x2 CHAR, x3 CHAR) RETURN CHAR DETERMINISTIC
  IS
    BEGIN

      RETURN CASE
             WHEN x1 = a AND x2 = b THEN 'Q1'
             WHEN x1 = a AND x2 = b AND x3 = c THEN 'Q2'
             END;

    END
SELECT x1, x2, x3,
       get_marker(x1, x2, x3) AS marker
  FROM original_table
 WHERE get_marker(x1, x2, x3) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you @diziaq. That was very kind of you. That really useful with me.

Answer (score 1):

If for `X3='c'` if you really need 2 rows, one with Q1 and another with Q1, then the union query is the best one.

I tried creating a CTE with `X1=a and X2=b` and then did a union later. The cost was bit more than the normal union query.

So go ahead with `union`.

Also if these columns are not indexed, try indexing them. Performance would improve.

Comment: Yeah, early i think Union is the best choose for this. But in my case, this table have too large data. Call this table 3 times per query, if use UNION, that mean i call 6 times for this.

Comment: Yeah. You can try indexing x1,x2 and x3 columns. Would improve performance.

If my answer works for you, then please accept it.

Comment: Actually, i have no privileges for change table index. Moreever, i have to select too many rows (~50), as you say i can't index for all of them (of course if i have right)